# how to find unlocalized strings in flutter/ easy_localization

Tags: flutter

Recently we complete a huge application with easy_localization package in flutter
but now I need to check is there any string in project that dose not follow this package rules and not compatible in different locales?
wrong pattern:

```
"str"
'str'
```

correct pattern

```
tr("str")
tr('str')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with these two regular expressions:

```
[^(]".*"[^)]
[^(]'.*'[^)]
```

that can be tested and improved in  [regex101](https://regex101.com/)
you can use it in vs code like this to find them

[image: vs code demo]
If you know better way or expression to solve it
please inform me at comments

Answer (score 0):

you can just search your project for anything that matches "str" using your editor and confirm it yourself

I'm not that good at regex but I think this will do it `[^(]".*"[^)]`